# Save Value and text in Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

hi i have a combobox in c# winform.
i have to save two things against each elemet. a Text which will be displayed to user and a id against that text.

in Asp.Net we can save these values in Text and Value fields of listbox..

but how to handle this situation in winform app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) to store data. And then bind it to your ComboBox. Remember to set ComboBox.ValueMember (points to ID field) and ComboBox.DisplayMember (points to Text field) properties.

Answer (score 0):

comboBox1.SelectedValue;
comboBox1.SelectedText;

These two will work for you.

Happy coding.

Comment: but this will be used to get the value and text. my question is how to save these (text, value)